# Laplace expansion of Pfaffian

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, pfaffian

I am reading about Pfaffian, which can be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian.

We know that the (general) Laplace expansion is very useful to compute determinants of matrices, and I wonder if there is such an expansion to compute Pfaffians (of skew-symmetric matrices). Fortunately, such formula exists https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian#Recursive_definition, however I do not know how to prove it.

Do you know any proof or any reference? And what is the general form of such formula, i.e., when we expand along $k>1$ rows and columns?

Comment: The Examples section of that Wikipedia article mentions skew-symmetric matrices at the bottom.

Comment: Sorry, but could you be more clear?

Comment: At the bottom of [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian#Examples), there's discussion of reducing skew-symmetric matrices, along with a link to another page. It's not an explicit answer to your question, just some place that looked like it would help ...

Comment: Ah I see... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It could be on pages 115 and 116 at the end of Chapter 7 of Northcott's book, Multilinear Algebra (the solution to exercise 8).